# What is the PCR error telling me?

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I tried running PCR and the results came out like this

```
> pcr.mod <- pcr(price~date+age+distance+stores+latitude+longitude, data = Estate.train, scale = TRUE, validation = "CV")
Error in cvsegments(nobj, k = segments, type = segment.type) : 
  More segments than observations requested
```

can someone explain to me what this means?